# Script to go to every subdirectory of a folder and run command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, subdirectory

I am trying to write a script that performs the following steps:
1. Go to every folder in a directory which was given as parameter when running the script.
2. Make a folder in each subdirectory called "Histogram"
3. Read out every file with the Ending *.jpg
4. Convert a picture into a txt-file by the command "Convert XY -format %c histogram:info:XY.txt
5. Move txt-file to folder "Histogram"
6. Go back to start directory and continue with next folder

This is what I got so far:

```
pfad="${1:-.}"
cd "$pfad/"
mkdir Histogram
for i in 'ls -1 *.jpg'
do
cat $1 |
convert $i -format %c histogram:info:"Histogram_$1'.txt"|
mv "Histogram_$i'.txt" Histogram/
```

It is still missing, that the script executes the command for each subdirectory, also the making of the folder and the moving of the txt-file in the folder does not work.

Comment: This is more a do my homework question. But anyway you can do a `dirs=\`find . -type d\`` and then iterate over dirs with `for dir in $dirs` as you have already done with `*.jpg`. Inside the loop you can create your dir and move the file

Comment: The result of this is that the scripts creates a folder in the start directory and does not access the subdirectorys. Therfore, also the second loop does not work as I get the feedback "cannot acces *jpg: No such file or directory" as there are no jpg-files in the start directory

Answer (score 0):

create a script which takes a list of absolute file name and creates Histrogram folder if not exists and creates txt file

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for absfile in "$@"; do
    dir=${absfile%/*}/Histogram
    file=${absfile##*/}
    mkdir -p "$dir" || exit 1
    convert "$absfile" -format %c histogram:info:"$dir/Histogram_$file.txt" || exit 1
done
```

call this script in  find command

```
find root_path -name '*.jpg' -exec ./script.sh {} +
```